# Is there a way to use cursorWordPart*Select command w/o capturing underscore?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a fan of sub-word captures, but I'm used to the sublime way where if you have a word with underscores, it will exclude the underscore from the capture like this:

[image: Sublime example]

In VScode, I setup my keyboard shortcuts to use the `cursorWordPartLeftSelect` and `cursorWordPartRightSelect`, but they include the underscore like this:

[image: VScode example]

Here are the lines from my config:

[image: VScode config]

Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 11):

Add the underscore character to the `Editor: Word Separators` list in the settings (just search for `separators`).

`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\|;:'",.<>/?_`     // with the underscore added at the end

I am a little surprised it isn't already there but it isn't.  Then your `WordPart` selectors won't include the underscores.

---

It looks like v1.44 adds a fix to this so that the `cursorwordpart`left/right acts like Sublime Text with respect to underscores.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93239.

Comment: This solves the problem, but with the caveat that now, `ctrl` + `arrow` which is supposed to move an entire word, stops at underscores.

Comment: I don't think you can have it both ways.  You are definig a `word` for vscode - there isn't a separate list of separators for the two commands.  Just hit the `ctrl+arrow` multiple times.

Comment: For me this misses the purpose of differentiating between words and word parts, so I'll have to pass. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with this extension, and removing underscores and hyphens from VS Code's word separators:
https://github.com/mlewand/vscode-select-part-of-word

Haven't had the time to dig into it and configure it to match Sublime Text yet but I'm praying this will be a part of the puzzle in getting VS Code to work like Sublime Text did!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this extension out.
I'm not sure since when, but the problem seems to be fixed (at least on my machine).
I'm currently using VS Code 1.49.1